# Connect text field and php

Tags: php, javascript, html, connection, textfield

I have a some code, but I don't now how to connect this with text field and PHP:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 

$url = $_GET['url']; 

if( ! empty($url)) 
{ 
    $data = file_get_contents($url); 

    $data = str_replace('<head>', '<head><base href="'.$url.'" /></base>', $data); 

    $data = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $data); 
    $data = preg_replace('#<iframe(.*?)></iframe>#is', '', $data); 

    $data .=  
    ' 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $("div").each(function(i){ 
        if($(this).css("position") == "fixed") $(this).css("display", "none"); 
    }); 
    </script> 
    ' 
    ; 

    die($data);  
} 

?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="author" content="Webarto" /> 

    <title>AdriaMart</title> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 

<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
iframe{width:100%;height:400px;} 
--> 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 

<input name="" type="text" />
<input name="" type="button" /
<iframe id="iframe" src="?url=http://kupime.com"></iframe> 

</body> 
</html>
```

I want to change the URL address when I type the address in the text field and click on the submit button. How can I do this?

Comment: what I need is to change url in iframe (http://kupime.com) with some other url when I tye url adress in text field

Comment: is there any answer ... maybe with ajax or ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED**

```
<!-- ... -->
<input id="iframe_url" name="" type="text" />
<input id="iframe_button" name="" type="button" />
<iframe id="iframe" src="?url=http://kupime.com"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('iframe_button').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = '?url=' + document.getElementById('iframe_url').value;
  };
</script>
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: @user1094631 You didn't give the button an id of `iframe_button`

Comment: yes, i did. I just copy your code. and there is button id=iframe_button

Comment: Sorry, I was in PHP mode and put a `.` where it should have been a `+`. Try edited version above.

Answer (score 1):

Add the text box and submit it.

it should look like this:

```
<intput type="text" name="url" />
```

That should do the trick if I understood you correctly.

Update:

change:

```
<input id="iframe_url" name="" type="text" />
```

to:

```
<input id="iframe_url" name="url" type="text" />
```

Update2:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input id="iframe_url" name="" type="text" />
<input type="submit" id="iframe_button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: change:    <input id="iframe_url" name="" type="text" />    to:   <input id="iframe_url" name="url" type="text" />

Comment: Add a form around your inputs and set type to get...I'll show you how in an edit above...

Comment: Additionally you shouldn't be using a "button", you should be using a "submit".